# Date data from Mysql only displays the default date in Blazor

Tags: c#, mysql, blazor

I have followed a tutorial about connecting Mysql to Blazor and i tried an experiment to add a date into it. and the result end up like this.
i have used Convert Zero DateTime and Allow Zero DateTime but it's did'nt work.

[image: Date showing default when i run the code]

[image: My Database]

Here is my code .razor file :

```
[Parameter]
public int ID { get; set; }



List<PegawaiModel> _pegawai;
//public PegawaiModel pegawai;
public PegawaiModel pegawai { get; set; }

private async Task InsertData()
{

    
    string sql = "insert into pegawai (NIK, Nama, Jabatan, Alamat, Tanggal_Bergabung) values (@NIK, @Nama, @Jabatan, @Alamat, @Tanggal_Bergabung);";

    await _data.SaveData(sql, new { nik = pegawai.NIK, nama = pegawai.Nama, jabatan = pegawai.Jabatan, alamat = pegawai.Alamat, tgl_gabung = pegawai.Tanggal_Bergabung}, _config.GetConnectionString("default"));
    OnInitializedAsync();
}


protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    string sql = "select * from pegawai";

    pegawai = new PegawaiModel();

    _pegawai = await _data.LoadData<PegawaiModel, dynamic>(sql, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("default"));

}
```

and here is the model :

```
namespace CluterZoneCorp.Model
{
public class PegawaiModel
{
    
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NIK { get; set; }
    public string Nama { get; set; }
    public string Jabatan { get; set; }
    public string Alamat { get; set; }
    //public DateTime? Tanggal_Bergabung { get; set; }
    //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
    //[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    //public DateTime Tanggal_Bergabung { get; set; }
    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Tanggal_Bergabung { get; set; }

    //public Byte Foto { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you temporarily convert that field to a string and see what is sent? I'll try and help when/if you reply. What is the datatype in the database? It's been a long time since I have used MySql.

Comment: Oke i will try it. tgl_gabung is date type in my database

Comment: i have tried convert it to string, the result are still same.
@BrianParker
can you check this? i put this code. is this code right for convert date to string?

    `code`protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
      {
        string sql = "select * from pegawai";



        pegawai = new PegawaiModel();
        pegawai.Tanggal_Bergabung.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        _pegawai = await _data.LoadData<PegawaiModel, dynamic>(sql, new { },     _config.GetConnectionString("default"));
    
    }`code`